# Symfony+Propel: Setting connection collation

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, propel, collation

I'm using Symfony 2.1.6 framework integrated with Propel 1.6.7 as database ORM through a MySQL Server 5.5.28 and I'm having problem to set database collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

My *app/config/config.yml*:

```
...
propel:
    dbal:
        driver:               %database_driver%
        user:                 %database_user%
        password:             %database_password%
        dsn:                  "%database_driver%:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%;charset=%database_charset%"
        options:
            MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND: "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
        attributes:           {}
```

(parameters are already defined in *app/config/parameters.yml*)

Without `options` it works, but with charset issues (MySQL defaults to `utf8_general_ci` collation, but database schema was defined with `utf8_unicode_ci`). If I use `options` as above Propel/Symfony raise a bunch of exceptions:

```
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 725  -+
at ErrorHandler ->handle ('2', 'Illegal string offset 'value'', '/var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php', '725', array('source' => array('MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' => 'SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci'), 'write_to' => array(), 'option' => 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND', 'optiondata' => 'SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci', 'key' => '1002'))
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 725  -+
at Propel ::processDriverOptions (array('MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' => 'SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci'), array())
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 668  -+
at Propel ::initConnection (array('dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=symfony;charset=utf8', 'user' => 'root', 'password' => '********', 'classname' => 'DebugPDO', 'options' => array('MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' => 'SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci'), 'attributes' => array(), 'settings' => array()), 'default')
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 576  -+
at Propel ::getMasterConnection ('default')
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 602  -+
at Propel ::getSlaveConnection ('default')
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/Propel.php at line 552  -+
at Propel ::getConnection ('default', 'read')
in /var/www/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php at line 1160  -+
at ModelCriteria ->find ()
in /var/www/src/Acme/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php at line 20  -+
at DefaultController ->fooAction ()
at call_user_func_array (array(object(DefaultController), 'fooAction'), array())
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1426  -+
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1390  -+
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1566  -+
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 617  -+
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in /var/www/web/app_dev.php at line 25  -+
```

I know that I can change *my.cnf* to define MySQL default collation directly from server config, but I need to set this at runtime... Am I missing something? How I should set `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` in *app/config/config.yml*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see source code [here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/1.6.7/runtime/lib/Propel.php#L725),

```
$value = $optiondata['value']; // this is line no 275
if (is_string($value) && strpos($value, '::') !== false) {
    if (!defined($value)) {
       throw new PropelException("Invalid PDO option/attribute value specified: ".$value);
    }
    $value = constant($value);
}
```

Its expecting an "value" key in option data, so try this

```
propel:
    dbal:
        driver:               %database_driver%
        user:                 %database_user%
        password:             %database_password%
        dsn:                  "%database_driver%:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%;charset=%database_charset%"
        options:
            MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND: { value: "SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci" }
        attributes:           {}
```

Or

you can also define queries which has to be executed immediately after connection opened

```
propel:
    dbal:
        default_connection:         default
        connections:
            default:
                # ...
                options:
                    ATTR_PERSISTENT: false
                attributes:
                    ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES: true
                settings:
                    charset:        { value: UTF8 }
                    queries:        { query: 'INSERT INTO BAR ('hey', 'there')' }
```

FYI: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/blob/1.1/Resources/doc/configuration.markdown

[Propel runtime configuration file](http://propelorm.org/reference/runtime-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your point of changing my.cnf, if the specific collation setting is required  only for the database you are going to use then I think its better to overwrite the collation setting while creating the DB by using the command " **create database db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci** " instead of changing it globally by editing my.cnf